# Facing "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory" while running on hadoop

Tags: java, gson

I am using GSON library (V 2.8.2 ) for my current project.  I am facing below mentioned exception while running on hadoop job tracker while it is running fine on YARN. I am using the same uber jar in both the modes.

I am creating gson instance using following snippet of code

```
 RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<parentGif> AbstractGifTypeAdapterFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
                .of(ParentGifParseImpl.class).registerSubtype(SubGifParseImpl.class);

 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(AbstractGifTypeAdapterFactory).create();
```

I added following Dependency in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
 <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
 <version>2.8.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(Lcom/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory;)Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
```

Comment: Is the hadoop job tracker maybe containing its own version of the `com.google.code.gson` jar? Then your code might end up using that version which might not have the mentioned `registerTypeAdapterFactory` method.

Comment: @LazerBass Interesting, do you know how can i verify the version used by hadoop job tracker? Thanks.